# xpath in the calibre editor

Tags: epub, calibre, editing, html, table-of-contents

### Abstract

In some search operations in calibre one can use an xpath expression to get the values for particular tags, i.e. the following expression:

```
//h:div[re:test(@class, "figbox", "i")]
```

selects the content of a "div" tag whose "class" attribute is set to "figbox", so in the following html line:

```
<div class="figbox">Volterra</div>
```

the preceding xpath expression returns the value "Volterra". This is useful to compile the ToC of a book and for other tasks.

### Question

Now, with the following processing-instructions

```
<?bag value="2" content="Volterra"?>
<?bag value="3" content="Ferrara"?>
```

which xpath expression can I use to obtain the value "Ferrara" but not "Volterra"?

### Fieldwork

With the calibre editor I've tried putting in a book the following line

```
<?bag value="3" content="Ferrara"?>
```

and testing the following expressions to add the word "Ferrara" in the ToC:

```
//processing-instruction("bag")[@value="3"]/@content

substring-before(substring-after(//processing-instruction('bag'), 'value="3" content="'), '"')
```

but in both cases I get only

```
"calibre, version 3.30.0
ERROR: No items found: No items were found that could be added to the Table of Contents.
```

Comment: Most of the posts here are read by fewer than 10 people. You're more likely to get an answer in the official [Calibre forum](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=166).  BTW, if you used heading tags, you could automatically generate TOCs.

Comment: @NemoXXX I posted in [Calibre forum](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=310319) but with no better fortune. Sadly I definitely need an help about processing instructions.